# Using coverage.py in Odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

How do you integrate `coverage.py` in testing out your custom modules in Odoo? I have already implemented some unit-test for the module but right now I would like to test for the test the code coverage of the test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Odoo Community Association continuous integration tools, [Maintainer Quality Tools](https://github.com/OCA/maintainer-quality-tools), do this and much more. You should consider reusing them.

Going straight to the point, you need to run something like:

```
coverage run /home/odoo-9.0/odoo.py -d mydb --stop-after-init --test-enable --init <module>
```

You may want to check the [MQT source code](https://github.com/OCA/maintainer-quality-tools/blob/d09724b605eb17176f425364bd9376e1119e2b7a/travis/test_server.py#L328) doing it, or see in action in a [TravisCI build](https://travis-ci.org/OCA/project/jobs/124719255#L563).